# Function $f(x)$ whose value is the same as its derivative for a constant

Tags: real-analysis

Can we construct a function $f(x)$ such that for every $x$

$f(x) =c$

and

$f'(x)=c$

What would be an example of such a function?

Comment: For all $x$?...

Comment: The derivative of a constant function is identically zero.

Comment: Well no:  the derivative of a constant is $2 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is identical to a constant, then it's derivative is $0$. So the only such function would be $f(x)=0 $ since $f'(x)=0$ also.

Answer (score 2):

Derivative of a constant is obviously zero..So if f(x)= a constant, only f(x)=0 can be applicable for the question you asked.

But if you want any variable functional value then "Exponential Function e^x" is always ready for you.

i.e f(x)= e^x

and f '(x)=e^x

Rather upto the nth derivative you'll get e^x ( n being a natural no )